# how does 'continue' work in this python code?

Tags: python, continue

I'm a bit confused, here, after "continue" is executed, it automatically jumps out of the current iteration and **does not update** the index, right?

```
def method(l):
    index = 0
    for element in l:

        #if element is number - skip it
        if not element in ['(', '{', '[', ']', '}', ')']:
            continue // THIS IS MY QUESTION
        index = index+1
        print("index currently is " + str(index)) 
    print("--------------------\nindex is : " + str(index))

t = ['4', '7', '{', '}', '(']
method(t)
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Comment: This is definitely an example of trying it in a simple console will help a tonne :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `continue` skips to the next item in the iterator that you are iterating through.

So in you case, it will move to the next item in the list `l` without adding `1` to the `index`.

To give a simpler example:

```
for i in range(10):
   if i == 5:
      continue
   print(i)
```

which would skip to the next item when it gets to `5`, outputting:

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2):

`continue` moves to the next iteration of a loop.

When `continue` is executed, subsequent code in the loop is skipped as the loop moves to the next iteration where the iterator is updated. So for your code, once `continue` is executed, subsequent code (i.e., updating `index` and `print`) will be skipped as the loop will move to the next iteration:

```
for element in l:

    #if element is number - skip it
    if not element in ['(', '{', '[', ']', '}', ')']:
       continue # when this executes, the loop will move to the next iteration
    # if continue executed, subsequent code in the loop won't run (i.e., next 2 lines)
    index = index+1
    print("index currently is " + str(index))
print("--------------------\nindex is : " + str(index))
```

Therefore, after "continue" is executed, the current iteration ends without updating `index`.